# Porting Github on Back4App

Tags: node.js, github, back4app

How do I install my copy of [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/) in my own Github account onto my Back4App backend?

What files need to go where?

On the Dashboard of my Back4App app, I have the 'Cloud Code' tab open. If shows 'Cloud' and 'Public' in the files section. I can add new files to each.

I do not think I have anything in the 'Public' section, as I will just be communicating with this app via another web host provider.

But what files of the PeerJS Github need to go to the 'Cloud' section?

Is there a faster way to do this, rather than copy each file separately?

Comment: Your complete whole application needs to go in the Cloud folder. You can also install any npm package you want by placing them in the package.json file dependencies. You can use the CLI to upload multiple files at once.